# RtlAdjustPrivilege is not adjusting privilege

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

My RtlAdjustPrivilege function doesn't set the privileges to my application but I looked at https://github.com/winsiderss/systeminformer/blob/master/phnt/include/ntrtl.h and it is defined in my program just like it is in there. Is something wrong with my code?

```
#include <Windows.h>

#define SE_SHUTDOWN_PRIVILEGE 19
#define SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE 20
#define SE_SYSTEMTIME_PRIVILEGE 12

typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* pdef_RtlAdjustPrivilege)(IN ULONG Privilege, IN BOOLEAN Enable, IN BOOLEAN CurrentThread, OUT PBOOLEAN WasEnabled);
pdef_RtlAdjustPrivilege RtlAdjustPrivilege;

BOOL EnablePrivilege(ULONG priv)
{
    HINSTANCE ntdll = LoadLibraryW(L"ntdll.dll");
    if (ntdll != NULL) {
        RtlAdjustPrivilege = (pdef_RtlAdjustPrivilege)GetProcAddress(ntdll, "RtlAdjustPrivilege");
        if (!RtlAdjustPrivilege) {
            FreeLibrary(ntdll);
            return FALSE;
        }
        RtlAdjustPrivilege(priv, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
    FreeLibrary(ntdll);
    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    EnablePrivilege(SE_SHUTDOWN_PRIVILEGE);
    //do something
}
```

Comment: and what RtlAdjustPrivilege return ? or it crash with 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0 ? last parameter cannot be 0

Comment: Why are you calling the Rtl version and not the normal win32 function?

Comment: @Anders is there a difference?

Comment: Use the documented API when you can. And you can get rid of GetProcAddress.